# How to label individual points in data set with use of SciDraw?

Tags: plotting, packages, scidraw

I'm trying to lable each point in data set and adjust corresponding TickLabels. Here is my code:

```
<< SciDraw`;
EM = {{3, 4.6928886 10^(-2)}, {2, 2.5835689 10^(-2)}, {1.3, 
1.440918 10^(-2)}, {1, 1.2898527 10^(-2)}};(*data set*)
maxEM = Max[#[[2]] & /@ EM];(*maximum of data set*)
Figure[
      FigurePanel[
               {
                DataPlot[EM, XAxisScale -> Log, DataLine -> {Show -> False}, 
                DataSymbol -> {SymbolSize -> 5, FillColor -> Firebrick}]
               },
               YPlotRange -> {0, maxEM + 0.01},
               XPlotRange -> {-0.045, 0.55},
               XTicks -> 
               LinTicks[{Log[10, EM[[4, 1]]], Log[10, EM[[3, 1]]], 
               N[Log[10, EM[[2, 1]]]], N[Log[10, EM[[1, 1]]]]}, {0}, 
               DecimalDigits -> 2],
               YTicks -> 
              LinTicks[Delete[#[[2]] & /@ EM, 3], Delete[#[[2]] & /@ EM, 3], 
              DecimalDigits -> 2],
              XFrameLabel -> textit["Log(step)"],
              YFrameLabel -> "EM", ShowFrameLabel -> True
                 ],
     Canvas -> {10, 10}
     ]
```

Please note that horizontal axis is logarithmic. The output is:
[image]

I would like to get something similiar to this:
[image]

Also I wonder if you can put some Graphics object like Circle[] on Canvas(outside of FigurePanel) in SciDraw. So something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert on `SciDraw`, perhaps one will chime in.  I'm sure the way to do what you are asking is somewhere in the accepted options, there are many of them

```
Options@DataPlot // Length
Options@FigurePanel // Length
Options@Multipanel // Length
(* 204 *)
(* 495 *)
(* 502 *)
```

Here is the best kludge I could work out using this package without learning all the options:

```
labels = Reverse@{"\"0h\"", "\"1h\"", "\"2h\"", "\"3h\""};
Figure[
 FigurePanel[{
   DataPlot[#1,
      XAxisScale -> Log,
      DataLine -> {Show -> False},
      DataSymbol -> {SymbolSize -> 5, FillColor -> Firebrick}, 
      CenterLabel -> #2, CenterTextNudge -> {0, 15}] & @@@ 
    Transpose[{{#, {#[[1]] + .001, #[[2]]}} & /@ EM, labels}]
   },
  YPlotRange -> {0, maxEM + 0.01},
  XPlotRange -> {-0.045, 0.55},
  XTicks -> 
   Evaluate[{N@Log10[#1[[1]]], #2} & @@@ Transpose[{EM, labels}]],
  YTicks -> 
   LinTicks[Delete[#[[2]] & /@ EM, 3], Delete[#[[2]] & /@ EM, 3], 
    DecimalDigits -> 2],
  XFrameLabel -> textit["Log(step)"],
  YFrameLabel -> "EM",
  ShowFrameLabel -> True],
 Canvas -> {10, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To bring in the circle, I think you need to make a `Multipanel`, but I gave up on that after a bit.  Here is the same plot using `ListLogLinearPlot`

```
labels = Reverse@{"\"0h\"", "\"1h\"", "\"2h\"", "\"3h\""};
Grid[
 {{Null, Graphics[Circle[], ImageSize -> 50]},
  {Show[
    ListLogLinearPlot[EM, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, FrameTicks ->
      {{LinTicks[Delete[#[[2]] & /@ EM, 3], Delete[#[[2]] & /@ EM, 3],
          DecimalDigits -> 2],
        StripTickLabels@
         LinTicks[Delete[#[[2]] & /@ EM, 3], 
          Delete[#[[2]] & /@ EM, 3], DecimalDigits -> 2]},
       {{Log[#1[[1]]], #2} & @@@ Transpose[{EM, labels}],
        {Log[#1[[1]]], ""} & @@@ Transpose[{EM, labels}]}},
     PlotRange -> {{0.9, 3.5}, {0, maxEM + 0.01}},
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Firebrick, PointSize[Large]],
     ImageSize -> 500, 
     BaseStyle -> {15, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"},
     FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"Log\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"(\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"step\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)\!\(\*
StyleBox[\")\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", "EM"}, 
     PlotTheme -> "Classic"],
    Graphics[
     Text[#2, {Log@#1[[1]], #1[[2]] + .0025}, BaseStyle -> 12] & @@@ 
      Transpose[{EM, labels}],
     ]
    ], Null}},
 Spacings -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great answer!!! As I noticed you even improved my code. Many, many thanks!